# Why is deuterium and tritium used in fusion reactions rather than two deuterium?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

Sorry if this question has been asked to death, but it doesn't make sense to me why we use a extremely rare isotope of hydrogen even though we have a much more abundant isotope. I am somewhat new to fusion, I just thought it'd be more cost efficient to use only deuterium?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout first Google Image of search 
fusion fission energy graph
You’ll see that binding energy is much higher with tritium.
So the temperature needed to entertain fusion is lower with tritium, making it easier.

Comment: Note that answers to questions on [physics.se] should be understandable entirely on their own merits; whatever is the first Google Image result for your search phrase today will not be the first result next year.